# create a VPN server in virtualbox guest box and access it from host

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vpn

I am trying to convert a ssh tunnel to a VPN connection. for some reason I can not use VPN outside my network. what I try to do is use ssh tunnel in a guest box (and share it using proxifier or similar app) and create a vpn server on that, then connect to that vpn from host.

host box: win7
guest box: win xp (with virtualbox)

I done most of that. guest have two network adapter. one bridged adapter to access to internet and second adapter is a host only adapter to access guest network on host side. I also shared internet to second adapter using ICS. second adapter IP address is 192.168.56.1. also setup incoming connection to accept vpn connections.

In host side I set default gateway of virtualbox adapter that guest use for second connection as IP of guest box (192.168.56.1).

now I created a PPTP VPN connection on host box and connect to (192.168.56.1). it connect successfully but when I connect to this vpn I lost internet connection on host.

what is wrong!?

this will be also enough if I could access internet though virtualbox adapter on host. so I share internet on guest, tunnel it and access it via host. actually I need a way to change ssh tunnel to a vpn connection or a network adapter either using such senario or whatever you think would be better.

Comment: VPNing through virtualizing adapters gets VERY hairy, you may wish to not do it as it is not a real-world scenario.  The VPN adapter is in itself virtual.

Comment: well I need a way to change ssh tunnel to a vpn connection or a network adapter either using such senario or whatever you think would be better.

Comment: I'm just cautioning against doing this within one computer using virtualization.  You can do this, just do it between two physical computers.